# Add view to the top of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout id="parent">
     <ImageView layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.nain);

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hello, world");

    parent.addView(textView);
    // parent.addView(textView, 0);
    // parent.addView(textView, 1);
    // parent.bringChildToFont(textView);
}
```

I inflated the code above as the content, and then, how can I add another view to the FrameLayout and it's on the top of the ImageView?

I had tried some several hours, but still don't know how to programmatically add another view to the top of the FrameLayout.

I found that it's easy to achieve the goal by add two children to the XML file. And at the end, I use a ViewStub and complete my work.

But I'm so curious about how to do this without a ViewStub.

**my solution:**

main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout id="parent">
     <ImageView layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <ViewStub id="stub">
</FrameLayout>
```

widget_text_view.xml:

```
<TextView />
```

ActivityMain.java

```
onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.nain);

    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.widget_text_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) stub.inflate();
}
```

Comment: I had tried addView(View), addView(View, index), bringChildToFront(childView), they all don't work in this case.

Comment: can you post the code where you try to add programatically

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add item to the top of another view. `android:layout_gravity` attribute. visite [This](http://sajidtutorials.blogspot.com/2015/05/user-interface-with-xml-framelayout.html). Or [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: I already know that how to achieve the goal by placing two child View in a XML file, but in this case, I just want to put one child in that layout file, and then programmatically add some children which will be on the top of the GroupView, say, I can see the child that programmatically added. (I couldn't see them via the `addChild()` method)